# Viewcomponent Dropdownlistfor obtener value - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlist

Llevo un rato dandole la vuelta a esto y no he conseguido tomar el value de un dropdownlistfor desde mi javascript, estoy comenzando con los viewcomponents en MVC Net Core.

Desde ya, gracias.

Creo un DropDownListFor de la siguiente manera:

```
@model SubCompanyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(n => n.SelectedSubCompanyId, Model.SubCompanies, Resource.GeneralSelectText)
}
```

Mediante el siguiente viewcomponent

```
public class DropDownCompanyViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

        public DropDownCompanyViewComponent(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
        {
            AppSettings = settings.Value;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            ServCliCostCenter.Client client = new ServCliCostCenter.Client(new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()) { BaseUrl = AppSettings.UrlAPIBackCostCenters };

            ICollection<ServCliCostCenter.SubCompany> subCompany = client.GetSubCompanyAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult().Values;

            var model = new SubCompanyModel
            {
                SubCompanies = new SelectList(subCompany, "IdSubCompany", "SubCompanyName", 1)
            };

            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Eso me genera el siguiente form:

```
<form action="/" method="post"><select data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedSubCompanyId field is required." id="SelectedSubCompanyId" name="SelectedSubCompanyId"><option value="">Please select an order template</option>
<option value="1">TEST1</option>
<option value="2">TEST2</option>
<option value="3">TEST3 </option>
</select><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8BLIbwwZ-LhAu_z4M8SoNFH9ecLEYtBRuUd8OidqIkuKds_93ubTjvJsaLmNkAByqfGCivXgezOQDBegEYv7k9Tm_qScPnyEC0y0GL5c0QAtuLR5ne5Cs1j2vOlpdLZqKyM9ZhuvLAO1Yb0Sf6fpTxU"></form>
```

Lo que quiero hacer y no he logrado, es obtener el value del select mediante javascript, lo he intentado de la siguientes maneras:

```
var e = document.getElementById("SelectedSubCompanyId");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;   //SELECTED INDEX SIEMPRE VIENE EN 0

var subCompanyId = $('#SelectedSubCompanyId').val(); //SIEMPRE TRAE EL VALUE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres obtener el valor seleccionado de un `Select`, debes hacerlo justamente **cuando el usuario lo selecciona**.

Esto lo puedes hacer en el evento `change()` del `Select` con jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SelectedSubCompanyId").change(function () {

            alert($("#SelectedSubCompanyId").val());

        });
    });
</script>
```